# When will the arrow reach the moving target?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Imagine following scenario in an infinite 2D plane: [Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9jyn.png)

A stationary archer wants to shoot an arrow at a moving target.

The target moves horizontally at a constant known speed, $S1$. The arrow moves forward at a constant known speed, $S2$ (it cannot change its direction once you shoot it).

The vertical distance from the archer to the target is known - let's call it $h$. The horizontal distance from the archer to the target is known - let's call it $x$. [Distances Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C1Hy.png)

In order to hit the target, the archer wants to know where it'll be when the arrow reaches it - so it needs to calculate the change in the target's x position: $\Delta$. (The horizontal distance from the target to the archer will be $x+\Delta$ when the arrow reaches it).

Easy enough, if $t$ is the time it takes the arrow to reach the target, $\Delta=S1*t$. Now let's find $t$ using the Pythagorean theorem for the distance to the future target: $$t=\frac{\sqrt {h^2+(x+\Delta)^2}}{S2}$$
There's my problem. The value of $t$ depends on $\Delta$, and the value of $\Delta$ depends on $t$.

How do I solve these equations?

(Note: $t$ and $\Delta$ are the only variables here, the rest are known parameters).

Comment: Careful here: $t$ is assumed to be _given_! "... if $t$ is the time it takes the arrow to reach the target". $t$ depends on $\Delta$, but $\Delta$ is _not_ dependent on $t$, but rather _given_ by $t$; you've already determined it. Square on both sides, substitute for $\Delta$ and solve for $t$.

Comment: Substitute $\Delta=S1\cdot t$ and solve the resulting quadratic equation for $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from

$$
S_2 t = \sqrt{h^2 + (x + S_1 t)^2}
$$

Take the square on both sides

$$
S_2^2 t^2 = h^2 + (x + S_1 t)^2 = h^2 + x^2 + 2S_1t + S_1^2t^2
$$

Rearrange things a bit

$$
(S_2^2 - S_1^2)\color{red}{t^2} -2 S_1 \color{red}{t} - (h^2 + x^2) = 0
$$

which is a quadratic equation in $\color{red}{t}$, can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! I solved the equation (hopefully correctly) and built this graph to visualize the result. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uextoipuor